# Command claims to need Argument

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Currently trying my hand at making a discord bot using Python. Before I get into the meat of it, there's only two commands so far, a ping and shutdown command.

When using the shutdown command, for some reason, I get an error message that it was missing a required argument, despite it never needing an argument.

Here's current code for the command:

```
from discord.ext import commands
class AdminCommands(commands.Cog):
    
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("kill loaded!")
    
    @commands.command(name="shutdown",
                      help= "For owner only! Shuts down the bot.")
    @commands.is_owner()
    async def kill(self, bot, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Shutting down now, see you later!")
        await bot.close()
        
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(AdminCommands(bot))
```

Expected behavior is that it will shut down, but I get met with my error handler saying this:

> "There's an argument missing! Use sb!help to figure out proper use."

Ping is structured identically, though the command doesn't need an argument. If needed I can provide code from the base bot. Any help on this is appreciated.

Edit: By request, added the traceback:

```
Ignoring exception in command shutdown:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File ".\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File ".\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File ".\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File ".\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ctx` needs to be the first arg after self.

Also you do not need bot as an argument at all, just use self.bot.close() in the command.

```py
    @commands.command(name="shutdown",
                      help= "For owner only! Shuts down the bot.")
    @commands.is_owner()
    async def kill(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Shutting down now, see you later!")
        await self.bot.close()
```